# Separate SQL queries per word for dynamic pages?

Tags: sql, database, dynamic, multilingual

I am creating multilang pages for a dynamic site 9ocial network) so all the page text is database driven. Question is if there are say 100 different words on the page in different places does that mean I need to include 1000 select SQL statements for each work to read it from the database? I have never worked with multi lang dynamic pages just pure hardcoded English only pages which was easy so not sure. There are stuff like page title bar, page meta data, page text, menu labels, footer etc. so each is a separate sql query I assume to pull the word?

Comment: For some things, you might be looking into using resource files and having one for each locale.  What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wouldn't necessarily be a SELECT statement for each item. If your schema has related items in the same table, these could be returned in a single call. 
[e.g. making some assumptions about your table structure]

```
SELECT page_title, page_text, page_footer, page_blah 
FROM page_table
WHERE page_id = 123 AND lang = 'FR'
```

For your collection (1-to-many) items, e.g. page meta data, you could consider views, pivots and/or unions to reduce the number of calls further (or live with a higher number of calls if the performance/maintainability is ok). To know whether views etc. are suitable you should post more details of your schema. 
hth, R

Comment: If i understand correctly a view is just for show to make the query look good. but it still has to do the same work as a non view query, so what is the benefit in terms of performance? I dont have the schema defined for the page text / multilang, doing it now hence the question. But for multilang it is the std key_id, key, lang_id

Comment: Sure, a view will not give a performance benefit over the non-view query. I saw it as an option to move away from the approach of numerous chatty SELECT statements, by using more complex queries, i.e. the performance gain is from fewer calls overall. The view may then provide a more maintainable, reusable implementation for this. And they look pretty too.